# Django Utils six for Django 3.1.5

Tags: django

I have a token generator that uses six

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six


class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp)  + six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

This runs on Django 2.2 but my boss told me to run this on latest 3.1.5. However, six was already depreciated.

I also checked this SO suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/65620383/13933721

Saying to do `pip install django-six` then change `from django.utils import six`  to `import six`

I did the installation and changes to the code but it gives error message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'`

I think I did something wrong or something is missing but I don't know how to proceed.

Here is my pip freeze for reference

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.5
django-six==1.0.4
djangorestframework==3.12.2
Pillow==8.1.0
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

**EDIT**

It should had been `pip install six` not `pip install django-six`

`pip install six` fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Offical django page says:

*Dont use it or switch to here* (https://pypi.org/project/six/)